# Bootstrap Scrollspy and Parallax

Tags: html, css, parallax, scrollspy

here is my html file:

[Html](https://hastebin.com/upenazatag.xml)

and here is my css File:

[CSS](https://hastebin.com/ucidoviyor.css)

the Problem is: if i am removing "***html***" from "***body, html***" in css in line 35, my scrollspy navbar is working, but my parralax effect is away.

But if i am adding "***html***" to "***body, html***" the parallax efect is working but not my scrollspy.

The Problem is at "***height : 100%***" but don´t know how to fix this.

I am working with bootstrap 4.

Comment: sorry but not getting what you exactly want?

Comment: @Zuber i want a website bith a bootstrap parralax background and a sticky-top navbar with a scrollspy. But if I am adding "height: 100%" to html in css the parallax background is working but not the scrollspy navbar. and if I am removing it the scrollspy navbar is working but the parallax backround dissapears.

Comment: @Zuber here is a Example how I want it: http://djteam-gp.de/

Comment: Try height:100vh; instead of height 100% doesnt work... I am still figuring out the reason for that. But width 100% works.

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene not working sry...

Comment: Its hard from your code to analyze where you have defined parallax effect. Also you have loaded bootstrap.css which is collection of all css, but after that you have loaded bootstrap-grid and bootstrap-reboot. You need to create jsfiddle with your issue so you could get immediate answers

Comment: In .bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 did you try with height:100vh instead of 100%

Comment: yes i tried with 100vh but doesn´t working

Comment: i will create a jsfiddle

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene here the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bq95yc0t/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bq95yc0t/1/ can you check this. I am not sure. I didnt change anything. I just added images.

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene yes thats like i have it. so the problem is ... if you scroll the highlight of the different sections is not working...

Answer (score 1):

change `css` of `sticky-top`

```
.sticky-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1020;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1L53ydLw/2/)

Comment: please check the fiddle, is that you need? @AndréSchüle

Comment: no the fiddle is not working... also there is no class sticky-top in this fiddle...

Comment: the scrollspy is not working but the parallax background is woking

Comment: Please check the fiddle again @AndréSchüle

Comment: not working... maybe we coud meet at teamspeak and i can explain you.... but here is a example how i want it...djteam-gp.de